# Background scrolling not working with firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a text area with a notebook look. when the scrolling appear after typing, i want the notebook background to scroll with the text.

It seems like `background-attachment: local` not working with FF even though it should be supported.

```
textarea{
    width: 300px;
    resize: none;
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: ProximaNova-Regular;
    border: 0;  
    padding: 0 10px;
    border: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fff 0, transparent 0),-webkit-linear-gradient(right, #fff 0, transparent 0),-webkit-linear-gradient(#fff 29px, #91D1D3 29px, #91D1D3 30px, #fff 30px);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #fff 0, transparent 0),-moz-linear-gradient(right, #fff 0, transparent 0),-moz-linear-gradient(#fff 29px, #91D1D3 29px, #91D1D3 30px, #fff 30px);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #fff 0, transparent 0),-ms-linear-gradient(right, #fff 0, transparent 0),-ms-linear-gradient(#fff 29px, #91D1D3 29px, #91D1D3 30px, #fff 30px);
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, #fff 0, transparent 0),linear-gradient(right, #fff 0, transparent 0),linear-gradient(#fff 29px, #91D1D3 29px, #91D1D3 30px, #fff 30px);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 40px;
    background-attachment: local;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #444;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRajqb

Comment: Looks like it might just not be working on textarea. When I replace that with a DIV element with enough content to get a scrollbar in your pen, then the desired effect shows.

Comment: ok i can live with it. Thanks!

Comment: You do not need the prefixed versions of `linear-gradient`, as all current browsers support the non-prefixed one. You are learning from old material! http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients